# Git master repository on central server?

Tags: installation, git, revision-control

currently i am working with subversion and trying to switch to git as an RCS. Maybe i don't understood the principle of git correct, but there is one big question:

Does git need some kind of server component which is responsible for holding the so called "master" repository? I couldn't find any information in the tutorials about setting up a git server component.
What i like to do is to setup a central git repository on my root server (Ubuntu) which is the "master" repository where all developers checkout and commit (i think it's called "pull" and "push" in git) their changes from the local repositories from.

Is this possible, or does git not have a central server component at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) on my Ubuntu server to manage all my personal projects. It's quite a lot of work to set up, but well worth it in my opinion.

You could also sign up for a free account on [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) itself, or the well-known (but unstable in my experience) [Github](http://github.com/).

Comment: Have you tried Github in the past month or so?  I'm obviously biased, but it's been a lot better since the move.

Comment: Both Gitorious and Github look nice. But Github seems to be be a service, or is there any download version availible for selfhosting.

Comment: @womble: No, I moved all my stuff off as soon as Github was up for long enough for me to do so. Seemed to be every time I needed it to be up, there was a problem. Once bitten, twice shy! :)

@Alexander: Aye, github is a free (public repo) or paid-for (private repos) service, whereas Gitorious is a free service and also an open-source project itself.

Comment: Gitosis (http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=summary) seems to be what i am looking for. I want to host the master repository by myselfe.

Comment: It looks like gitolite is preferred over gitosis now: http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite  Also, I found this article useful: http://toroid.org/ams/git-central-repo-howto

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a dedicated server to provide access to Git repositories, but it's just as easy for internal use to just have everyone access the git repo using SSH.  If you do want to use a git server, you want to run `git daemon --help`.

Answer (score 1):

With GIT you CAN hav a central Repository, but you do not have to. If you like, you can work with one central repository where all developer sync. But you could as well have other approaches - e.g. departments push and pull to a "department-hub" and all these are synecd to a central repository...

for more see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460502/is-using-a-central-repository-going-against-gits-purpose